# Quarkus RESTeasy Encoded QueryParam

Tags: encoding, jax-rs, resteasy, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am trying to fit my microprofile RestClient to make GET calls to an external API which expects the format of a date query in the following format:

```
https://some_uri/?query=date%3A%282022%5C-01%5C-01%29?&fmt=json
```

The above corresponds to a non-encoded uri of the form: `date:(yyyy\-MM\-dd)`. I came across [@Encoded](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/resteasy_reference_guide/_encoded_and_encoding) for that purpose. I have defined my RestClient like so:

```java
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyService {

    @GET
    @Path("release/")
    @Encoded
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    MyResponse getReleasesByQuery(
          @QueryParam("query") @Encoded String query,
          @QueryParam("fmt") String format
    );
}
```

which I invoke like this:

```java
String encodeQuery(LocalDate date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    var formatted = formatter.format(date);
    var query = "date%3A%28" + formatted + "%29";  // corresponds to date:(yyyy-MM-dd)
    return query.replace("-", "%5C-");
}

myService.getReleasesByQuery(encodeQuery(Datetime.now()), "json")
```

However (when enabling the http logging) I see the following getting called instead:

```
GET /ws/2/service/?query=date%25253A%2525282022%255C-02%255C-12%252529&fmt=json
```

Which as far as I can tell does encode the % into the UTF counterpart (%25).

So essentially I want to disable the encoding and do it myself instead. Am I misusing or misunderstanding this somehow?

I am on Quarkus version 2.4.1.

Comment: Does not `@Encoded` encode what you have just manually encoded? So would not simply removing the annotation (since you have already provided the encoded form) make it work?

Comment: You are actually right. Previously I was having issues with the backslash prior to the dashes. This seems to have been something else!